# Running in Linux versus through Eclipse?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, model-view-controller

I was giving a program to look at, I am very new to java but they run it through Linux and use the command

```
" java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath $PROGRAM_DIR/bin account.Driver"
```

I'm trying to run it through eclipse but its giving a file not found in main error. Is there any way to get it to run through eclipse or is this something to do with the code its self?

Here is the main function:

```
package account.util;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

import account.controller.AccountController;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String accountDataFilename = args[0];
        new AccountController(accountDataFilename); 

    }

}
```

Side note: this program is MVC style coding

Comment: Your class is declared in the `account.util` package, but you're specifying one in the `account` package on the command line.

Comment: Sorry I forgot I was messing with it but its the original now

Answer (score 0):

You are not launching your Java Application from the directory you think you are. The default is most likely your project's root location. If that's not what you intended, specify it.

http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-executionArgs.htm?cp=1_3_6_6